# How to get python 3.5.1 running with heroku local?

Tags: python, heroku

I have been following this quick start: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python

but was wondering how I could get 'heroku local' to run with python 3.5.1? I already changed runtime.txt to set it to python 3.5.1, but still it would load up 2.7's dependencies.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!
You could also have defined your local procfile and launch everytime `heroku local -f local.procfile` but that's boring.
So I asked for support in heroku local repo on Github ([here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-local/issues/41)) and I liked a lot the solution he gave me.

Basically you add /bin folder in your PATH like this: `export PATH=./bin:$PATH` and then in the root of your project you do `ln -s $(which python3) ./bin/python` in order to create a symlink only in the scope of your project!

Comment: thx, but this work on one shell session and need to manually set it every time, right?