# Running Django on Heroku Local using Python 3.X on MacOSX

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-development-server

I want to run my django app on `heroku local` and i wish to run python 3.X.  I have Python 3.6 installed from the python website.  However the default version of python on the system in 2.7.  How can I get heroku local to use python 3?  Should I always use a virtual environment to do this?

Comment: did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47050264/5250746) ?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I did not see it, but that looks like a good solution.